# Javascript - why the variable is always empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, qr-code, barcode-scanner

`newcode();` is executed by external input (keyboard or SNAPI). As a result console log shows `barcode_id` has a value `1234`.

But then when `button_scan()` is clicked/executed it always tells `barcode_id` empty.

How to make sure when `newcode()` is executed it really edit the `barcode_id`?

```js
 var barcode_id = '';
    
    function button_scan() {  
      if(barcode_id!='') { // WHY????? always empty console shows: 1234
        alert("DENY");
        return false;
      }
    
      // ALLOW
    }
    
    function newcode() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        var new_barcode = $('#barcode').val();
        if(new_barcode!='') {
          barcode_id = new_barcode;
          $('#barcode').val(''); 
          console.log('>>> ', barcode_id);   // prints value: 1234    
        }   
      }, 500);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value='' name='barcode' id='barcode' onkeydown="newcode();"/>
 <button onclick="button_scan()">Button</button>
```

Comment: works for me it alerts "DENY" because it is not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(barcode_id!='') //<---If the barcode_id is not an empty string
```

try:

```
if(barcode_id=='')//<---If the barcode_id IS an empty string
```